# JavaFX target drag event null

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I have a for loop that creates multiple rectangle shapes and I am adding `DragDropped` events to them. For some reason even though the source reports it as successful (and the color of the rectangle changes) when I go to check the target it is reported as `null`.

`ParkingSpot` is just an class that extends `Rectangle` and adds a new more bits of info I need to store in them.

Also, `TransferMode.COPY` is set on the source and target(`ParkingSpot`) so that shouldn't be an issue.

```
private ParkingSpot createRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height){
   ParkingSpot vehicleSpot = new ParkingSpot(x, y, width, height);

...

spot.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
   System.out.println("onDragDropped");
   Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
   boolean success = false;
   if (db.hasString()) {
        spot.setTestinfo(db.getString());
        System.out.println( " added to " + spot.getTestinfo());
        spot.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        success = true;
    }
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
});
}
```

In this `spot.setFill(Color.BLUE);` works but for some reason `spot.getTestinfo()` doesn't. The same goes with me using spot.getX() which also works. I don't understand how it could set the color but not the text. My apologies if this is a bit brief. I can add more if needed.

EDIT: This is how I am creating the rectangles:

```
for (ParkingSpot spot : parkingSpots){
    pane.getChildren().add(createDraggableRectangle(spot.getX(), spot.getY(), spot.getWidth(), spot.getHeight()));
}
```

This loops through a List of ParkingSpots and adds them to the list for saving and loading.

These are the ListView items and how I copy their info to the dragboard. I know this works as when I drop it onto the shape I have it output the contents it dropped.

```
listCell.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
     /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
     /* allow any transfer mode */
     Dragboard db = listCell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);

     /* Put a string on a dragboard */
     ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
     content.putString(listCell.getText());
     db.setContent(content);
     System.out.println("Dragging" + content);

     event.consume();
});
```

Everything here is in my `Controller.java` class.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Comment: Just added more. Let me know if that is enough.

Comment: I got it to work by checking the X,Y coordinates but it definitely hackish...